# postgres not setting foreign key to null when truncating

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to truncate a set of tables, but it keeps complaining about a foreign key.
but that foreign key is set to `on delete Set null`

to reproduce:

```
create table test_players (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255));
create table test_items (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255), player_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY (player_id) REFERENCES test_players(id) ON DELETE SET NULL);
```

now if you truncate the test_players it will complain:

```
ERROR:  cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint
DETAIL:  Table "test_items" references "test_players".
HINT:  Truncate table "test_items" at the same time, or use TRUNCATE ... CASCADE.
SQL state: 0A000
```

what must I do to make me be able to delete `test_players` **without** deleting the `test_items`?

Comment: It basically tells you what to do: `use TRUNCATE ... CASCADE`

Comment: @AlexeySoshin I don't want to remove the test_items (i've updated the question)

Comment: You posted the create table commands, but you didn't post how you're trying to delete them. Please add this to the question too.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you are attempting. You will have to do this in  3 steps.

1. Update test_items and for each player_id. Well technically you don't need this, but if you don't give yourself data integrity issues.
2. Drop the test_items to test_players FK.
3. Then truncate test_players

The reason is that truncate basically just zaps the table, it does NOT process individual rows. Therefore it would not process the FK set null, it throws the error you got instead. In fact even if the child table is empty, or for that matter even if the parent is empty. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=75db209f5018ac1ecf6bbcbf64f4391c) here. The fiddle also contains a function to do it, and a test for it.

The of course you could just Delete from test_players and let the triggers take care of updating test_items. Takes longer, esp if larger table, but you keep your FK. Of course there's

4. Recreate your FK.